# How to change vertical and horizontal unit based on a fraction of width and height of an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have to overlay some texts on a PDF form. As converting the PDF form to EPS with `pdftops` produces unsatisfying result, I will not use PSTricks code below.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\M{4}% columns
\def\N{4}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale
\def\filename{example-image-a}% filename


\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridcolor=yellow,
    subgridcolor=gray,
    subgriddiv=10,
    griddots=0,
    subgriddots=5,
    gridwidth=0.4pt,
    subgridwidth=0.2pt,
}

\psset
{
   xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\M,
   yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\N,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-\M,-\N)(\M,\N)
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \rput[bl](1,1){This is a text.}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output I want to achieve looks like the following.

[image]

Instead I will use TikZ. My problem is how to set the horizontal and vertical unit in TikZ. More precisely, how to do the following in TikZ?

```
\psset
{
   xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\M,
   yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\N,
}
```

### MWE in TikZ

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,dvipsnames,border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\M{4}% columns
\def\N{4}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale
\def\filename{example-image-a.pdf}% filename


\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,x=0.5\wd\IBox/\M\relax,y=0.5\ht\IBox/\N\relax]
    \node (image) at (0,0) {\usebox\IBox};
    \node at (1,1) {some text goes here};
    \draw[help lines,red,step=1](-\M,-\N) grid (\M,\N);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

DONE! Problem solved!

Comment: More general, how to mimic the PSTricks output with TikZ?

Comment: Never mimic others! ;-). BTW problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to convert pdf to ps, since pstricks code can be compiled with `pdflatex`: you just have to load pstricks with option `pdf` and launch the compiler with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX)  or `--shell-escape` (TeXLive, MacTeX). Then pstricks will launch `auto-pst-pdf` and you'll get a `pdf` image.

Code modified:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}%

\def\M{4}% columns
\def\N{4}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale
\def\filename{example-image-a}% filename

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} 

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridcolor=yellow,
    subgridcolor=gray,
    subgriddiv=10,
    griddots=0,
    subgriddots=5,
    gridwidth=0.4pt,
    subgridwidth=0.2pt,
}

\psset
{
   xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\M\relax,
   yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\N\relax,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-\M,-\N)(\M,\N)
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \rput[bl](1,1){This is a text.}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure no EPS generated on the fly?

Comment: I don't know, really. I suppose there is an intermediate .eps file that is generated, then epstopdf and pdfcrop are launched and finally the generated .pdf image is incorporated in the main file. There remains no .eps file in the aux directory.

Comment: There will be _no_ eps file.

Comment: @Herbert: Didn't know that. Thanks for the information.